# converting histogram bars to symbols in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, plot, histogram

In my function below, from time to time (**please run a few times to see**), I get an error message from inside the `data.frame` that says `x` and `y` differ by 2 rows.

I was wondering how this occasional error could be fixed?

```
 x = rnorm(1e2)
 h = hist(x = x, plot = F)

DF = data.frame(
 x = unlist(sapply(1:length(h$mids), function(i) rep(h$mids[i], each = h$counts[i]))),
 y = unlist(sapply(h$counts, function(c) 1:c)))

plot(DF$x, DF$y)
```

`Error in data.frame(x = unlist(sapply(1:length(h$mids), function(i) rep(h$mids[i],  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 100, 102`

Comment: When I run your code in my session, I don't have any error message and I get the plot.

Comment: @dc37, as I very clearly emphasize in my original post you need to **run a few times** to see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get some `h$counts` as 0 and when you run `unlist(sapply(h$counts, function(c) 1:c)))` it generates a sequence from `1:0` which is unwanted. You can modify the way you create the dataframe and it should work ok.

```
DF1 <- data.frame(x = rep(h$mids, h$counts),y = sequence(h$counts))
```